# timezone offset is not working in ios devices

Tags: javascript

I am trying to get timezone offset with `var offset = new Date().getTimezoneOffset();`. It is working fine in window and android devices. But for IOS device it is getting '0' value. Please let me know if anyone have solution for this.

Comment: Are you sure the timezone is set correctly in the device?

Comment: How are you testing? If you are using BrowserStack, their devices appear to be configured to use the UTC time zone.

Comment: Yes  I am using browserstack for testing and it is returing only UTC timzone